# What video codecs does Temasys WebRTC support

Tags: webrtc

What video codecs does Temasys WebRTC support?  Both H.264 and VP8 maybe?

(Yes, This is regarding Temasys plugin that is used by IE and Safari to have WebRTC capabilities.)

Also, bonus question, what audio codecs are supported?

Thanks!

Henry

Comment: [looks like your google group post got an answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/temasys-discuss-webrtcplugin/codec/temasys-discuss-webrtcplugin/aElp-1qJpFE/9pfM4t9ePcoJ)

Comment: Yup, I guess the for the sake of completeness:  VP8, G711, OPUS and the 
Commercial plugin supports H264, G722,Isaac

Answer (score 0):

For future records:

The free plugin support

- vp8 for video
- opus and g.711 for audio

The commercial plugin comes with some optional extra codecs:

- Isaac
- g.722
- h264